# Frame creaking even without BB and cranks

Tags: frames, creak

my 2011 Aluminum Specialized Stumpjumper HT Comp creaks a lot when pedaling, especially from a standing position. I tried changing the BB, greasing the cranks etc. but nothing helped. When I removed the cranks and BB and pushed on the frame from the side the noise was the same as when pedaling so i think it has to be the frame creaking. The frame also did not seem very stiff when pushed on like this (compared to my road bike and cheap dept. store bike).

From what I remember, the creak was always there. I tried looking for possible cracks in the frame but found only surface level chips in the paint. Can I do something about this? Should I be worried?

Comment: Could also be the rear wheel. Maybe it’s just the spokes rubbing on each other at the crossings? I’d try some lubricant on the spoke crossings to eliminate possible creaks from there. And maybe check the spoke tension.

Comment: @Michael Wow, thanks a lot! I sprayed a little oil into the spoke crossings and also into the rear QR and its completely silent now! I would've never though of that!

Comment: Glad to hear! I recently serviced the MTB of a friend which had a similar “problem” but it was more noticeable because there were visible rust spots at the spoke crossings and squeezing pairs of spokes together easily reproduced the sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Michael, it was the rubbing crossings of the spokes maybe in combination with the rear QR axle.